# Can someone suggest a good wiki for our dev team: asp.net / active directory / c# / IIS

Tags: c#, wiki, ntlm

Can someone suggest a good wiki for our dev team please.

I know this question has been asked before, and I've been looking at foswiki, it looks good but won't work well in our environment: asp.net / active directory / c# / IIS.

We're hoping to find one that works well in our typical windows environment: asp.net / sql server / iis / active directory NTLM authentication.

Any recommendations would be great, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[ScrewTurn Wiki](http://www.screwturn.eu/) (It's what Chuck Norris uses)

Comment: +1 for the chuck norris reference :)

Comment: +1 the AD Plugin works great.

Comment: Sadly, Chuck Norris doesn't believe in technology or science.

Comment: If chuck norris doesn't believe in something, does that thing then cease to exist?

Answer (score 1):

If you have SharePoint, or if you can install SharePoint(Standard Edition will be enough), you can use SP's wiki sites which works on exactly the technologies that you have mentioned and will provide good OOB integration for your environment.